# How to override model's default attributes using FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have an `Order` model with a default attribute `status_id` whose default value is 1.

I use `rspec` for testing my rails app. I create an object in a describe block as follows:

```
let!(:order) { create(:order, status_id: 3) }
```

When I execute the test, I examine the state of the `order` object and find that `order.status_id` is equal to 3, but when I do `Order.last.status_id` I get 1 instead of 3. If I do `Order.all.count` I get 1. When I check object ids of `order` and `Order.last` they are the same. However, I noticed that their memory location is different.

I wonder why am I seeing this behaviour and how can I fix it so that `Order.last.status_id` becomes 3 as set in the `create` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to a `before_save` callback in the `Order` model. I forgot to check there, but now see that when the callback is called it sets the `status_id` to the default value based on the value of another attribute.